# Freqtrade Shorting Strategy implementing

Tags: python, pandas, trading, ta-lib

I am trying to apply a short/leverage strategy using freqtrade but getting stuck in one place I made the necessary changes for that(can_short: bool = True, def leverage,populate_exit_trend,populate_entry_trend,populate_indicators, "trading_mode": "futures", "margin_mode": "isolated", "liquidation_buffer":0.05) but still I am stuck at the strategy part it is not trading in short mode not event in DRY RUN so anybody ca help me with that

I tried this thing in Strategy Customization(can_short: bool = True, def leverage,populate_exit_trend,populate_entry_trend,populate_indicators, "trading_mode": "futures", "margin_mode": "isolated", "liquidation_buffer":0.05) and I am expecting the short mode trading in the freqtrade

is there anybody who that guide me with these problems

thank you in advance!

Comment: Please ensure your code is properly formatted and fully reproducible. In it's current state, we can't reproduce your issue